# Python2.6 run error failing to import md5

Tags: python, unix

i downloaded python2.6 and installed it on Solaris10 operating system which ships with python2.4 already installed however when tried importing the md5 module i was getting this error

```
 import md5
__main__:1: DeprecationWarning: the md5 module is deprecated; use hashlib instead
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/md5.py", line 10, in 
    from hashlib import md5
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/hashlib.py", line 136, in 
    md5 = __get_builtin_constructor('md5')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/hashlib.py", line 63, in __get_builtin_constructor
    import _md5
ImportError: No module named _md5
```

PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.6

Answer (score 3):

See http://docs.python.org/library/md5.html:

> Deprecated since version 2.5: Use the `hashlib` module instead.

Not much changes for you - you should import the `haslib` module and call `hashlib.md5()` instead of `md5.new()`.

**Edit**: Then again, I just verified that module `md5` normally imports correctly in Python 2.6 despite showing a warning. It will simply fall back to loading `hashlib` which apparently happened in your case as well. `hashlib` then imports module `_md5` and if I understand correctly this one is compiled into Python. I guess your Python is compiled without MD5 support then?

Comment: thanx but still not working am actually trying to install reportlab lib but even still it when i try <pre>import hashlib</pre> am still getting the same error with <pre>python2.6 setup.py install</pre>

Comment: well yah sure all i had to do was repeat the installation with the ssl library in my path and was all good thanx though